# Remove 1000's separator from column in CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python script where I'm importing a csv that has commas in values over 1000. These values are strings in the csv. I need to remove the commas from the values, and convert the strings to rounded floats inside the csv before it's imported into Python.

I've tried appending all the new values to a list to use the `csv.writer`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to have the writer only replace the values in the column that have commas. Here's what I have so far. :

```
import csv

RoomReport = r'path_to_csv'
new_values_list = []

f = open(RoomReport, "r")
reader = csv.reader(f)
writer = csv.writer(f)

for row in reader:
     useable_area = row[7]

     if "," in useable_area:
         useable_area_no_comma = useable_area.replace(",","")
         useable_area_rounded = int(round(float(useable_area_no_comma)))
         new_values_list.append(useable_area_rounded)


f.close()
```

Comment: Your CSV as separator uses comma? Or semicolon (, or ;)

Comment: No, the numbers over 1000 in a column have commas like 1,089. I need 1089. And I need to change this inside the csv before it's imported and joined to another table in the Python script.

Comment: Bill: What separator character is used _between_ the numbers in each row? If it's a comma, then it will beimpossible to tell which ones are part of a column with a number > 1000 in it and which commas are separating the numbers. Please [edit] you question and show what a few rows of the input file look like. This issue can be avoided if the numbers have quotes surrounding them.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I see what you're getting at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, this can only be done if the input csv file is formatted in a way that will allow the commas in the numbers to be differentiated from the commas *between* each one of them.

Here's an example of one way it could be done (by quoting all the values):

```
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7,123.6","8","9"
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","1,000","8","9"
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","20,000","8","9"
```

Here's code that will do what you want. It uses the `locale.atof` function to simplify cleaning up the number:

```
import csv
import locale

# Set local to someplace that uses a comma for the thousands separator.
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'English_US.1252')

RoomReport = r'RoomReport.csv'
cleaned_report = r'RoomReport_cleaned.csv'
new_values_list = []

with open(RoomReport, "r", newline='') as inp:
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if "," in row[7]:
            row[7] = int(round(locale.atof(row[7])))

        new_values_list.append(row)

# Create cleaned-up output file.
with open(cleaned_report, "w", newline='') as outp:
    csv.writer(outp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL).writerows(new_values_list)
```

The `RoomReport_cleaned.csv` it creates from the example input will contain this:

```
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7124","8","9"
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","1000","8","9"
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","20000","8","9"
```

Note that since the values in the output no longer have commas embedded in them, the quoting all fields is not longer necessary—so could be left out by **not** specifying `csv.QUOTE_ALL`.

Comment: Thank you. The simplest solution is to have the field formatted as a float to begin with.

Comment: Bill: It's fairly obvious that the problem wouldn't exist if the input csv was formatted differently, but you never mentioned that was even a possibility in your question—which makes me wonder why you bothered asking it at all...

Comment: I actually don't know if it's possible. I don't know anything about Tririga or how it outputs reports. The csv comes to me from a different department. I can easliy reformat the fields in Excel, but I need this process to be totally automated.

Comment: Bill: Thanks, however I suggest you do talk to someone in the other department because I strongly suspect the output could be formatted differently (although I know zip about Tririga). The reason is that the less preprocessing there needs to be done to first, the better off you'll be (i.e. less chance of it breaking later as well as less code to maintain).

Comment: I was able to solve this by converting the csv to a geodatabase table (this is a GIS process) and reformatting the fields.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
import re
from sys import stdout

isnum = re.compile('^[0-9, ]+$')
non = re.compile('[, ]')

fd = StringIO()
out = csv.writer(fd)
out.writerow(['foo','1,000,000',19])
out.writerow(['bar','1,234,567',20])

fd.seek(0)
inp = csv.reader(fd)
out = csv.writer(stdout)
for row in inp:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
        if isnum.match(x):
            row[i] = float(non.sub('', x))
    out.writerow(row)
```